# Expo eas build IOS with provisioningProfile file , distributionCertificate file and distributionCertificate password

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I am working on a react native expo project. I have submitted the app to the google play store but I am having a problem with submitting the app to the app store. my client didn’t share his apple ide access with me. he gave me provisioningProfile file, distributionCertificate file, and distributionCertificate password. How I can submit it with this information? He also gave me the app store connect admin access to my apple account. So How can I build ios for app store submission?

my eas.json

```json
{
    "build": {
        "ios": {
            "distributionCertificate": {
                "path": "iosdata/ios_distribution.p12",
                "password": "password"
            },
            "provisioningProfile": {
                "path": "iosdata/combengalcreativemediarhgdict.mobileprovision"
            },
            "distribution": "store"
        }
    }
}
```

when I run eas build --platform ios
it gives me an error

what is the proper way to do it for ios

Comment: Format your json, please

Comment: "platform ios it gives me an error" - what is the error?